# How to get a byte array of a pdf archive from a GET requisition?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an api that renames a byte array from a pdf file, but when I do a get request I can not get that byte array. The following message appears in the browser console:

> ERROR  {…} ​ error: {…} ​​ error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected
>   character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
>       Angular 8 ​​ text: "%PDF-1.5\n%����\n3 0 obj\n<>stream\nx���Mj�0\u0010��:�[:\u001bU?�~�-���bj�\u000b]�X\t\u000eN�8�!s�^��\u0017u\u000b�)8\u000ch`xo�'�\u0013yqD*\u0018��J�:�N\u0004\u0016a���\n��\u0005ܞ<�rp\u0006�!��킶�0���M�[\u001a\u001bh˨�?f\u0013̬�4[\u0012��+r_\u0017���:��\u000c�;kW\u001fm/�X�@n%M,474�������qC�<]>�,�g\u0013��A)C�\u0018\"f�DB\"��\u001c!\u0014G_W���\u0013�E�\u0018�Ծ�,�\u0007`b��0��?��7�_�R\nendstream\nendobj\n1
>   0
>   obj\n<>/Contents
>   3 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<>/ProcSet [/PDF
>   /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<>>>/Parent 4 0
>   R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n[1 0 R/XYZ 0 852
>   0]\nendobj\n2 0
>   obj\n<>\nendobj\n4
>   0 obj\n<>\nendobj\n6 0
>   obj\n<>\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<>\nendobj\n8 0 obj\n<>>>\nendobj\n9 0
>   obj\n<>\nendobj\nxref\n0 10\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000000301 00000 n \n0000000577 00000 n \n0000000015 00000 n \n0000000665 00000 n
>   \n0000000542 00000 n \n0000000728 00000 n \n0000000782 00000 n
>   \n0000000814 00000 n \n0000000917 00000 n \ntrailer\n<<0f3db8438dad491480ff1017eef9db67>]/Root
>   8 0 R/Size 10>>\nstartxref\n1125\n%%EOF\n" ​​ : Object { …
>   } ​ headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null,
>   lazyInit: lazyInit()  } ​ message: "Http failure during parsing for
>   http://localhost:9000/jasper/relatorio/testejasper" ​ name:
>   "HttpErrorResponse" ​ ok: false ​ status: 200 ​ statusText: "OK" ​
>   url: "http://localhost:9000/jasper/relatorio/testejasper" ​
>   : Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse()  }
>   core.js:15724
>       Angular 4
>       RxJS 5
>       Angular 11

How do I get this byte array without this error occurring?

I have also tried to pass this configuration to the request:

```
new HttpHeaders({Accept: 'application/pdf', 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', responseType: 'blob'});
```

Comment: is the endpoint suppose to return a byte array?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around `'Accept'` and `'responseType'`? Seems like your JSON isn't valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The responseType should not be in the header. It's a separate parameter.

```
this.http.get(url, { headers: ... , responseType: 'blob' })
```